# How to sample from a distribution approximated by a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, neural-networks, density-estimation

There are a few models already that approximate distributions with a neural network i.e.: energy models define a density function $f(x)= e^{S(x,w)}/Z$ where $S$ is a neural network and $Z$ is a normalizing constant.

For simplicity lets assume I have trained an nn-function that approximates the cumulative density instead $F(x)= S(x,w)$

How can I go about sampling from the distribution?

Comment: What is $w$?   ___

Comment: @Cryo $w$s are the weights of the neural network

Comment: The question has no generic answer. Since $x\mapsto S(x)$ is a black box function, it has no redeeming feature that could be exploited by algorithms like accept-reject or ratio of uniforms. The only general solution I can suggest is to use a Markov chain Monte Carlo method, since they only require the availability of $S$.

Comment: @Xi'an Ah thank you - Now it makes sense why VAE for example make the prior assumption